# How do you convert an array of {"name":"myName","value":"myValue"} objects into an object of "myName":"myValue" pairs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, key-value-coding

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm sure this would be easy for the experienced person.

The SimpleDB getAttributes function of Amazon AWS SDK for Node.JS returns an array of data like this:

```
my_JSON_object = {"Attributes":[{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"}]}
```

I want to convert it into a simple object like this:

```
my_JSON_object = {"Attributes":{"myName":"myValue","myName":"myValue",...}}
```

So that I can use dot-syntax to access things, such as: Attributes.myName etc.

How do I do such a conversion?

Comment: I assume that the objects are not all identical? Otherwise you'll end up with a single object, and all of your remaining data will be lost.

Comment: No they are not all identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var my_JSON_object = {"Attributes":[{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},{"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"}]}

var my_new_JSON_object = { 'Attributes' : {} };

my_JSON_object.Attributes.forEach( function ( value, index ) {
    my_new_JSON_object.Attributes[ value.Name ] = value.Value;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {"Attributes":[
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"},
    {"Name":"myName","Value":"myValue"}
]}

var attrs = json.Attributes.slice(0);

json.Attributes = {};

for(var i = 0, len = attrs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var attr = json.Attributes[i],
        key = attr.Name,
        val = attr.Value;

    json.Attributes[key] = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org) is an excellent lib for doing such things. It will make your code cleaner and easier to maintain.

```
var result = _.chain(my_JSON_object.Attributes)
.map(function(item){return [item.Name, item.Value]})
.object().value();
```

*This might be a little overwhelming if you are new to the language but trust me in the long run it's going to be mighty helpful.*